# Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=257 "The file “Documents” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it."

Tags: ios

I have a problem accessing my files.
I am trying to create a file and send it over FTP. However, when I tried to read the file I created, I got this error message. Can you check where did I made a mistake?

The FTP upload was from https://gist.github.com/Nirma/fb9991be776107d17fdcd6ed2aa02876

The TXT file was created successfully with following codes, I can view it on my iPad simulator.

```
// Create TXTFile
let fileName = "test.txt"
self.save(text: "some text shown here", toDirectory: self.documentDirectory(), withFileName: fileName)
self.read(fromDocumentsWithFileName: fileName)
```

But the error happens when I execute the FTPupload codes.

```
    // FTP upload
    let ftp = FTPUpload(baseUrl: "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX", userName: "XXXXXXX", password: "XXXXXXX", directoryPath: "XXXXX")
    
    let url = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!

    
    do {
        ***let data = try Data(contentsOf: url as URL, options: [ .alwaysMapped, .uncached])***

    ftp.send(data: data , with: "test.txt") { (success) in

            print("success")
            }
            print(data)
            }
            catch {
            print(error)
        }
}
```

I have tracked down that the line with stars creates the error which shows I don't have the permission to view the file.

Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible that you are simply missing the "test.txt" part in your URL? When you try to make data from contents of URL you should have `url.appendingPathComponent("test.txt")`

Comment: Yes. you are right.. Such a stupid error I made..